# jquery url string manipulation and character removing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three cases:

1) when the string looks like this  `/televisions?3dtv=true` - I need to remove `?3dtv=true` from it

2) when the string looks like this `/televisions?3dtv=true&brand=panasonic` - I need to remove `&brand=panasonic` from it

3) when the string looks like this `/televisions?3dtv=true&brand=panasonic&led=true` - I need to remove everything after last & including & so - `&led=true`

I guess number 2 and 3 are the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, `lastIndexOf` is only supported in IE9, so alternatively you can consider regular expressions:

```
var href = $(obj).next().attr('href').replace(/(?:&[^&]*|\?[^?]*)$/, '');
```

I updated the answer accordingly to the new requirements. The expression will either replace everything from the last `&` on or, if there is none, from `?`. As the alternation is evaluated from left to right, it is guaranteed that `&...` is replaced if it is present.

Expression explained:

```
/                 # start expression
  (?:             # open non-capturing group
      &           # match & literally
      [^&]*       # match any character but & as often as possible
      |           # OR
      \?          # match ? literally
      [^?]*       # match any character but ? as often as possible
  )               # close group
  $               # match the end of the string
/                 # end expression
```

Comment: +1 for support, I was unaware of that.  This link mentions it.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff679972%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Comment: I just found out recently as well.... unfortunately all the good functions are never supported in IE ;) (of course I'm exaggerating)

Comment: I missed a little something though. After I add my first ?something=something it doesn't do ?s=s but it does ?something=something&s=s. So I would need to have &s=s removed in that case, and ?something=something removed in first case. Should I create new question for that?

Comment: @bobek: I suggest you edit your question and explain it in more detail. Because I'm a bit confused now when you want to do what.

Comment: @bobek: Updated my answer... please check whether it fits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of substring a lastIndexOf.

```
var str = "/televisions?brand=panasonic?3dtv=true";
var newstr = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf('?'));
```

Please note that this is simply JavaScript and does not use any aspect of the jquery library.